# Selecting a date form the datTimePicker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

Here is a code snippet where in I have to select a proper date to book an appointment, it should do a simple validation that the date selected for the appointment is a date which is either the current date or later than that.

```
if (dateTimePicker1.Value < DateTime.Now)
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Date Selected is not Proper";
else (dateTimePicker1.Value >= DateTime.Now)
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Date Selected is " + dateTimePicker.Value;
```

However, here when I select the Current date it always goes in the if block.When ever I select a date later than the current date it works fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because DateTime.Now includes the time of the day, try DateTime.Today this only gets the date.

Answer (score 4):

You are forgetting about the time portion of the DateTime. You should use this instead:

```
if (dateTimePicker1.Value < DateTime.Today)
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Date Selected is not Proper";
else (dateTimePicker1.Value >= DateTime.Today)
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Date Selected is " + dateTimePicker.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

because of the `DateTime.Now` not only returning the data, it also returns the time. so to fix that:

use `DateTime.Now.Date` instead of `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 2):

DateTime.Now includes **both** the date and the time, and
'2011-07-29' is always less than '2011-07-29 13:50:00'

Use `DateTime.Now.Date`, or `DateTime.Today` for this kind of comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

The DateTimePicker has a MinimumDate property that will do this checking for you -- have you tried that?  Here is the documentation:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate(v=vs.80).aspx
```

Also, keep in mind that DateTime.Now has hours/minutes/seconds - it's not clear from your example if you want to compare just the date portion of the DateTime...?

Hope this helps,

John

Answer (score 0):

that is due to the milisecond difference.. you need to check only the date part not the time part... try using a `TimeSpan` with only date in it this should solve your problem.